# Python re substitute adds extra backslash chars

Tags: python, regex

I have a json string enclosed in single quotes. Hence i am escaping single quotes inside string with a single backslash.

When i write the output to a file, it writes two backslashes in the place of one.

A simplified example looks like,

```
import re
re.sub(r"'", r"\'", "abcd\'")
```

It writes to the file,

```
abcd\\'
```

But i prefer it to write,

```
abcd\'
```

Comment: How are you writing it to the file?

Comment: using open(file).write

Comment: If you do a straight `write()`, you will get neither result, you will get `abcd\'` - the quotes (and double backslash) are happening because you are writing the `repr()` to the file somehow. Please give the full code example that we can run to create a file with the text you gave in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work perfectly well:

```
>py -3
>>> import re
>>> with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
...     file.write(re.sub(r"'", r"\'", "abcd\'"))
...
6

>cat test.txt
abcd\'
```

When Python displays a string with a backslash, it will display it as an escaped string - this doesn't mean the extra backslash exists, it's just there to differentiate between an escape character and a real backslash.

```
>>> r"abcd\'"
"abcd\\'"
>>> print(r"abcd\'")
abcd\'
```